# Mongodb-hadoop-connector create lots of partitions even if I add query to it

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, apache-spark

I have a really large mongo table, I wanna do some analyze on it using spark , it's so large that I don't want to load the whole database. But it looks like it always scan the whole database and split them into tons of partitions even if I pass a `mongo.input.query` to it. I am using [mongo-hadoop](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop) to load it, and my codes look like this:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val mongoConfig = new Configuration()

val beginDate = new Date(2016 - 1900,6,7)

println("the begin data is: =========== >" + beginDate)

val beginId = new ObjectId(beginDate, 0,0.toShort,0)

mongoConfig.set("mongo.input.uri",
    "mongodb://mymongoduri/mongodb.mongocollection")

val queryStr = """{"_id": {"$gt" : {"$oid":"beginDate" }}}""".replace("beginDate", beginId.toString)
mongoConfig.set("mongo.input.query", queryStr)
mongoConfig.set("mongo.input.fields", """{ "its.src":-1, "its._id":-1, "its.cid": -1}""")

val documents = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
  mongoConfig,                // Configuration
  classOf[MongoInputFormat],  // InputFormat
  classOf[Object],            // Key type
  classOf[BSONObject])        // Value type

val OUTPUT_PATH = if(ENV == Some("dev")){
  s"./result"
} else{
  s"s3://${OUTPUT_BUCKET}/output/graph/${beginDate}"
}

documents.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
  OUTPUT_PATH,
  classOf[Object],
  classOf[BSONObject],
  classOf[BSONFileOutputFormat[Object, BSONObject]]
)
```

It ends up with tons of empty files in s3, which is not my expected result (and it waste lots of money).

I have read the document, it said `mongo.input.query` only `filter the input collection with a query` , can I just load the data as what I query ? Not just filtering them.

Or, **Can I just store those partition which is not empty?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

spark hadoop connector for mongo always read whole collection and make partition accordingly and then filter the object using the input query. As you are saving the document RDD, it will always save the partitions whether it is empty or not.

you can repartition the RDD to 1. Or use `documents.coalesce(1).saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(....)`

Comment: Great thanks, I have tried coalesce(20) but looks like it's too much to make 100k partitions into one, I am trying  coalesce(10000).coalesce(1000).coalesce(100).coalesce(20). BTW, are there any connector that won't read the whole collection? I just wanna query part of it.

Comment: Hi, pls read my answer, spark hadoop connector do provide a splitter to use the query. You don't need to scan the whole database .

Comment: nice. i was not aware of it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the codes very carefully . And I found that the default splitter always scan the whole database while the `com.mongodb.hadoop.splitter.MongoPaginatingSplitter` will apply the query when you do the splitting.

And than, I found that there is something in their wiki under configuration `mongo.splitter.class`:

`com.mongodb.hadoop.splitter.MongoPaginatingSplitter` :

*This Splitter builds incremental range queries to cover a query. This Splitter requires a bit more work to calculate split boundaries, but it performs better than the other splitters when a **mongo.input.query** is given.*

So I think this should be the final answer to my question.